# Removing steps from FuelUx Wizard by value

Tags: jquery, fuelux

I can remove the steps in a fuelux wizard by index like this:

```
$('#ApplicationWizard').wizard('removeSteps', 6, 1);
```

But I have several dynamic steps generated server side and I would like a way to remove steps by value

Something like

```
$('#ApplicationWizard').wizard('removeSteps', "Wizard Content");
```

So far I havent found a possible way to do this, any ideas ?

Comment: build a hashmap of steps and look up number in hashmap